How to Include host name in metrics labels with OpenTelemetry Collector?
I'm using the OpenTelemetry Collector to gather metrics from my application, and I want to include the host name in the metrics labels. This will help me identify which host the metrics are coming from when they're aggregated in my monitoring system.
Im trying to config my open telemetry collector like this but it does not work:
receivers:
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: 'node-exporter'
          static_configs:
            - targets: [ '0.0.0.0:9100']

processors:
  resourcedetection:
    detectors: [system]
    override: true
    system:
      resource_attributes:
        host.name:
          enabled: true
        host.id:
          enabled: false


exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:9464"
    const_labels:
      hostname: "${HOSTNAME}"
      hostip: "${HOST_IP}"

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [prometheus]
      processors: [resourcedetection]
      exporters: [prometheus]

Is there a specific way to achieve this? What am I missing in my configuration?
